# Como verificar se um dado existe na tabela antes de inserir MySQL + Python

Tags: mysql, python

Estou tentando verificar se um dado já existe na base de dados antes de inserir.

Meu código está assim:

```
nome = input("Insira seu usuario: ")
seleciona = "SELECT nomes FROM slogin"
cursor.execute(seleciona)
resultado = cursor.fetchall()
if nome in resultado
    print('Usuario Já Cadastrado')
else:
    print('Cadastro realizado')
```

Porém, não funciona. Como eu poderia arrumar, o que está errado no código?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Imagine que você tem uma grande empresa que usa seu sistema e você tenha como resultado de `SELECT nomes FROM slogin` mais de 100 mil registros. Imagine que cada um dos 100 mil usuários efetua o login ao mesmo tempo. Você vai logo perceber que seu sistema vai paralizar, porque você além de fazer uma pesquisa que retorna 100 mil você também vai ter que percorrer esses 100 mil registros para verificar se ele existe.

Então qual é a opção?

O melhor aqui é usar o próprio banco de dados para fazer essa pesquisa:
Você diz ao MySQL: Selecione os `Nomes` vindos da tabela `Slogin` onde Nome é igual ao Nome fornecido (digitado no input)

O banco de dados com seu mecanismo de busca nativo vai ser muito mais rápido em encontrar a resposta do que você trazer todos os registros e procurar por você mesmo.

Aqui uma sugestão de código:

```
nome = input("Insira seu usuario: ")
seleciona = "SELECT nomes FROM slogin WHERE nomes ='{}'".format(nome)
cursor.execute(seleciona)
resultado = cursor.fetchall()
if len(resultado)!=0:  #Verifica se o retorno contém alguma linha
    print('Usuario Já Cadastrado')
else:
    print('Cadastro realizado')
```

Comment: "*banco de dados com seu mecanismo de busca nativo vai ser muito mais rápido em encontrar a resposta*", não necessariamente, pois dependendo de como a tabela foi definida essa consulta pode resultar em um FULL SCAN e demorar até mais que a consulta original (o que pesa na original é a transferência de dados, não o tempo de consulta). Sem contar que fazer um SELECT antes do INSERT gera uma condição de corrida na aplicação. O ideal é definir a coluna como UNIQUE mesmo e tentar inserir direto. Se já existir, dará erro.

Comment: Correto. Tentei dar uma resposta o mais simples, sem alterar muito o código inicial, pois vi que o usuário está começando. Fazer com que a inserção gere um erro Violação de Chave (ou de Contraint) e o tratatemento deste erro ser considerado como "Usuário Existente", apesar de correto, me parece um pouco avançado.